# How to export the bulk of images in content in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, images

I need to export all images in content tab in marketing cloud. Here uploading option available. But I need to export/download. This option not available. Could anybody please tell me, How to export all images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy way to export images from SFMC, it is likely an effort to keep users on platform instead of moving to another service.

What I would recommend to pull bulk sets of images is via the [REST API asset query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm) using the [asset types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/base-asset-types.htm) for images. Now a caveat is that this will only pull those from Content Builder and that it will pull the URLs of the images, not the full image itself.

You then would need to use a third party service to parse through the returned JSON and then download the images from the URL. If you don't have something that can do this, there is a bit more duct tape manual process you can do.

1. First, you take the JSON returned from the REST API
2. You copy your JSON and use a [JSON-to-CSV converter](http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm). This will let you easily copy/paste all the URLs.
3. Copy all the URLs and then open a [Bulk downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki) to download the images based off the URL list you gathered.

There may be other solutions out there, but this is the best I have been able to find that will handle bulk downloads.

Comment: Thank you for given reply..